# Selenium executable script in java

Tags: selenium

I created a Selenium automated script using Java.

I developed this script in Eclipse and whenever I want to run the script I have to open eclipse and then I run it.

As all necessary Jars are required to run Selenium Java script but I would like an executable file for the same such that I click on the script it will start executing and will do all the work by itself.

Is it possible ?

As of now my script is opening my mail and entering email id and password and then it's clicking on login button.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it in several steps:

- add all steps in main method
- build jar file
- write .bat file to run your jar file(java doesn't create executable files). There are a lot of how do it in web

Answer (score 0):

Put your java code in a Maven project.

use maven-assembly-plugin

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

after in a .bat file (on Windows) or .sh file (on Unix):

```
java -jar yourJarFile.jar
```